# Help in converting Trigger to Batch class

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

All, here is my trigger and I want to convert this trigger into a batch class. I have 3 objects on this trigger. Account, Margin__C and commission__c.

**Use case:** This trigger currently run on Margin__C Object. When Margin__C is updated or inserted, it looks at date range between yr_StartDate__c and yr_endDate__c and compares it with object 'commission__c's field ‘Final_Date__c’. If ‘Final_Date__c’ falls between any of these dates, it sums the amount in ‘Gross_Commission__c’ field and updates it on Account record under Gross__C. The trigger runs well however when I try to convert it to batch class, it calculate all the amount in the  commission__c and puts it on the Account record. I only need it calculate when Gross_Commission__c falls between yr_StartDate__c and yr_endDate__c. Can someone pls help me batch class for trigger below?

```
    trigger CalculateMargins on Margin__c (before update, before insert) {

    Map <id,commission__c> AdvMap = New Map  <id,commission__c>  ();
      Map <id,Account> AccMap = New Map  <id,Account>  ();

    Set <id> MarginSets = New Set <id> ();
    For (Margin__c Pay : Trigger.New) {
        MarginSets.add(Pay.Id);

    }

    List <commission__c> CommsList = [SELECT ID, Gross_Commission__c,Margin__c,Accounts__c FROM commission__c WHERE Margin__c IN : MarginSets];
              system.debug('list of CommsList: '+ CommsList);


            Map<Id, Account> c= new Map<Id, Account>();

        for (commission__c ps : CommsList)
        { 
            Account Acc = new Account(Id = ps.Accounts__c);
            Acc.Gross__C = 0;
            AccountMap.put(ps.Accounts__c, Acc);
        }


                For (Margin__c Margin : Trigger.New) {

                    Date Startdate = Margin.yr_StartDate__c;
                    Date enddate = Margin.yr_EndDate__c;

                    system.debug(Startdate + '@@@' +  enddate);


        for (commission__c     ps : [select Accounts__c, Gross_Commission__c, Margin__c
                                     from commission__c
                                     where    Final_Date__c >= :Startdate  
                                              AND Final_Date__c <= :enddate])
        {
            Account accs = AccountMap.get(ps.Accounts__c);

            if (ps.Gross_Commission__c != null && ps.Accounts__c != null && ps.Margin__c != null)
            {
                accs.Gross__C += ps.Gross_Commission__c;

            }
        }

       update AccountMap.values();


    }    
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] for tips on getting the most from the Community - specifically, you should demonstrate an attempt at writing the batch class

Answer (score 0):

@Tom,
You should be able to achieve this by passing the values 'Margin.yr_StartDate__c' and 'Margin.yr_EndDate__c' to the batch class using a vf page.

In the start method of the batch class, you could code a query to return all the rows falling under the date ranges defined by the Start/End date that the user enters on the vf page.